Error during web bundling of React Native Expo App
I get the following error during 'npx expo start'& run the web version of my react native app.
Unable to resolve module ../../Utilities/Platform from \node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\TextInput\TextInputState.js:
I am new to react native Pl. guide on which files/folders to edit to resolve this error.
Note: the android version of the build works fine.
Thanks in advance.
enter image description here
following some suggested solutions , I tried to use postinstall to create a empty module, but getting errors in that as well. Not sure how to do it correctly.

This question is similar to: Unable to resolve module ../Utilities/Platform - Expo Web. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I have found the issue but don't know how to solve it @WilhelmErasmus .
I am using stripe integrations in my app.
When I run the web build of React Native the Native files checkout-form.native.tsx & stripe-provider.tsx  are run from the components folder instead of the web version ( checkout-form & stripe-provider.web.tsx).
In my app/home/index.tsx I am using  import import CheckoutForm from "../components/checkout-form"; without the extensions for metro bundler to auto pickup.
How to solve this ?
